# Write from Javascript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My question is pretty simple, i have a php code :

`$var_here = "<script type="text/javascript">document.write("9")</script>";`

```
$result_comment_submit = "INSERT INTO feed_comment_" . $var_here . " (full_name,comment,date_time)" .  " VALUES('$commenter_name','$commenter_comment',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%h:%i %p,  %W %M %e'))";
```

(it's a simple example)
I want `$var_here` to display a `9` in the 2nd variable. 
So, would `document.write()` be able to do that for me.

Comment: This is impossible. PHP runs on the server first, then sends its output to the web browser. JavaScript runs on the web browser.

Comment: @Chris..Please check with my example..it will return 9..Thanks

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar, your answer will output the query *to the browser*. But the OP is building an SQL query. Surely outputting it to the browser isn't the goal, but rather running that query on the back-end.

Comment: @Chris..Yes agree...you are right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work as per your expectation..run below code..for testing purpose removed last string..

```
<?php
$var_here = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write('9')</script>";
echo $result_comment_submit = "INSERT INTO feed_comment_" . $var_here . "";
?>
```